# Setting Download path for Python Selenium via FirefoxProfile, missing file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Trying to use Selenium to download a file. The file appears in my browser after "loading" , but the file does not appear in my specified path after the test completes.

```
    files_path = os.path.join(ui_path, "files")

    elif client_type == 'firefox':
        os.path.exists(fr'{files_path}')
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", files_path)
        profile.update_preferences()

        options = Options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
```

I've set a debug point before the test completes and `about:preferences` interface in FF indeed shows that that the download path is set to my path, and I dont see any error in my logs, but I don't see the downloaded file in my specified path. I adjusted the path manually to "Desktop", and still nothing

Comment: >The file appears in my browser after "loading" , _it should have the path where it's saved if it's showing in browser_

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this? Whats showing in my browser search bar is only the url from the aws s3 path its supposed to be downloading from. And I did a global search in my machine for the file name, and get nothing.